# Jenkins Multi-Line parameters with batch file

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

I am creating a new freestyle project in `Jenkins` and wanted to pass parameters with my batch file.

I created a multi-line string parameter in the `Command` section of the `Execute Windows batch command` box:

```
echo The build names are: %Build%

gitPull.bat (Pass in the variables here?)
```

But it only shows the first line of string.

After doing some research, I found out that batch command cannot handle multi-line strings, so I thought if the user can enter one line of string with comma between each string to separate it, then I could somehow store that in a variable.

For example:

```
"Hello,John,Doe"
```

Then I want to pass those variables separately into my batch file called `gitPull.bat` but I'm not sure how I can do this.

[image: screen shot of my windows batch command]

Comment: Have you considered or tried placing everything on a single line but separating each original line with an ampersand? In fact have you tried anything at all? Without doing so it simply means you're expecting us to make all of the effort which is not really how this site is supposed to work, _especially given that you haven't even asked a specific question_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I kind of figured it out, unless there is a better improvement. So I stored a single line in a list and separated with comma, which I was able to echo it how I wanted it to. This is how I did it.

```
@echo off
echo list = "%Build%"
for %%a in ("%Build:,=" "%") do (
   echo name is %%a
)
```

And with passing it with gitPull.bat, I just passed the build like:

```
gitPull.bat %Build%
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, **Multi-Line parameter** is used as common text-area in user forms. So this input is used to enter several words and maybe press enter key to write more words.

It will be complex, pass several words and "\n" as single parameter to your gitPull.bat

A workaround could be using **groovy** convert your multiline text:

```
https://github.com/app/repo.git
branch
other word
```

to :

```
"https://github.com/app/repo.git" "branch" "other word"
```

So your **gitPull.bat** receive 3 parameters

Or

```
"https://github.com/app/repo.git , branch , other word"
```

So your **gitPull.bat** receive 1 parameter and you cloud split using "," as separator.

> An advice could be create several simple parameters instead multiline parameter.

Comment: Thanks, but we cannot use groovy so I have done it the second way